# How to get phonetic matches with KeywordQuery or FullTextSqlQuery in people search?

Tags: search, people-search, phonetics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [KeywordQuery & Enabling phonetic results](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/9699/keywordquery-enabling-phonetic-results)

When I use the OOTB People Search, phonetic matches are returned (i.e. searching for "jon" returns both "jon" and "john"; however, when I use KeywordQuery or the FullTextSqlQuery classes they are not.

Here is what my KeywordQuery object looks like:

```
var query = new KeywordQuery(SPContext.Current.Site)
            {
                ResultTypes = ResultType.RelevantResults,
                EnablePhonetic = true,
                EnableStemming = true,
                EnableNicknames = true,
                HiddenConstraints = "scope:\"People\"",
                QueryText = searchText

            };
```

Does anyone have any ideas on what the OOTB people is using or what I need to to do differently?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem - Ended up solving it myself.

[How to enable phonetic results when using KeywordQuery?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/9699/keywordquery-enabling-phonetic-results)